# Failed to connect to the control user as defined in the configuration

Tags: mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpnvz.png)

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server refused the connection. You should check the host, or username and password in the config.inc.php configuration file and make sure that they match the information given to you by the administrator of the MySQL server.

This is the config.inc.php page.

```
<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

Comment: Please include the error messages as text and not as a screenshot.  That said, the account seems to be locked.  Have you tried a different control user/password combination?   Also, this isn't a programming question, rather a setup question(which probably is suited for ServerFault.)

Comment: I can't do anything just check config.inc.php and I don't know what to do on that page

Comment: "mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/4151): Access denied, this account is locked && Failed to connect to the control user as defined in the configuration. && phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server refused to connect. You should check the host or username and password in the config.inc.php configuration file and make sure they match the information given to you by the MySQL server administrator. " These are the only errors I encountered

Comment: Do you have a valid username/password credential that you use to access the mysql instance?  Do you even have MySQL installed/set up?   Either way, try asking in Serverfault.   This isn't a programming question.

Comment: No password, just the username (root), but I locked the account responsible for phpmyadmin in the database, then I got a white page with error codes

Comment: Why did you lock the root username and use the root username to log in?  If you've locked it, you can't use it.  Either unlock it or create a new username/password and put that in your config.php .

Comment: I couldn't connect to one of my projects, and I closed it, thinking that was what caused the problem, and to my surprise I couldn't get into phpmyadmin. I can't open it because phpmyadmin is locked

Comment: How do I create a username and password?

Comment: You're going to have to ask in Serverfault.